# Is there a way to limit the user inputs to two or three options

Tags: java, user-input

In the userInput function in Java has the person type in anything, is there anyway I could limit that to 2 options. Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Intelijence {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Scanner playerInput;
        playerInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String Question1;

        System.out.println("Ugh, I need some coffee");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("'What kind of coffee should he drink'");
        Question1 = playerInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println(Question1);
    }
}
```

So how can I set the option to something like light or dark roast?

Comment: Use a menu... select 1 for light and 2 for dark. Prompt should be in a while loop. Be sure to include validation.

Comment: Does my answer help?

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> acceptableAnswers = List.of("Light", "Dark", "Iced");
if (!acceptableAnswers.contains(Question1)) {
    System.out.println("You don't know anything about coffee, do you?");
}
```

You should then probably ask for a new input, which I leave as an exercise to the reader.

BTW, "Question1" is a bad name for a variable for two reasons: 1) it contains an answer, not a question, and 2) variable names start with a lowercase letter in Java by convention.

(Had to edit that because I am clueless about coffee.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `do...while` loop to loop until the user enters a valid input.

```
do {
    System.out.println("'What kind of coffee should he drink'");
    Question1 = playerInput.nextLine();
} while(!Question1.equals("light roast") && !Question1.equals("dark roast"));
```

For a larger amount of options, you can use a `Set` to store all the accepted ones.

```
final Set<String> accepted = Set.of("light roast", "dark roast");
do {
    System.out.println("'What kind of coffee should he drink'");
    Question1 = playerInput.nextLine();
} while(!accepted.contains(Question1));
```

Comment: Do not put all the options into the loop condition one by one, that approach works if there are only two options, maybe with three, but for everything more than that it becomes really hard to read.